# Java Script Function is not Defined

Tags: php, javascript, undefined-function

I am getting the following error from the chrome developer tool

> Uncaught ReferenceError: searchRequests is not defined
>   searchProcess.php:174  onclick.

When I click on hyperlink produced from `engine.php`, I don't get the alert from the `searchRequests` function. I'm not sure what the problem is, I appreciate any advice given. Here is my code:

**`searchProcess.php`**

```
<?php
include '../include/engine.php';
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var instrID;
    var cat;

    $(window).load(function(){

    });

    var newheight = $(window).height();


    function searchRequests(instr)
    {

        alert("in searchResults");
        instrID = instr;
        alert(instrID);

    }

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    drawSearchResults($var1, $var2, $var3, $var3, $var4); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**`engine.php`**

```
<?php
function drawSearchResults($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo ("<tr>");
        echo ("<td id='InstrumentID'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='searchRequests($row[InstrumentID])'>$row[InstrumentID]</a></td>");
    echo ("</tr>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Move `function searchRequests` to somewhere outside of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: or maybe fix the jQuery path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `searchRequests` is not in scope outside of the `$(document).ready()`. Move it outside of `$(document).ready()`.

In general you shouldn't embed your javascript in the html. Much nicer:

```
$('#InstrumentID a').click(someFunctionThatIsInScope);
```

And you can put that code in the `$(document).ready()` block. In addition the function you call will get an event object that you can use to get any values you might need from the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is private. You are hiding it from global scope since it is inside the ready function. Do not use inline event handlers, use on() to attach events!